# Symfony 2 dynamic embedded forms, wrong (entity) type

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities with a on to many relationship.

One "Entry" has n "Tags". Now I want to insert a new Entry with Tags. The form consist of a collection of "Tag" forms which can be dynamically added via javascript. One field is added by default in the controller code.

When the form gets submittet and I iterate over the Tags for the Entry, only the first one (which has been added in the controller, not via javascript) has the proper entity type. The other ones are just arrays:

```
object(Entity\Type)[88]
   private 'id' => null
   private 'field' => null
   private 'type' => string 'S' (length=1)

array (size=3)
  'field' => null
  'type' => string 'S' (length=1)
```

The "Entry" controller:

```
$entity = new Entry();
$entity->getParameters()->add(new EntryTag());

$form = $this->createForm($this->get('entryform'),$entity);

if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    $formData = $form->getData();
    foreach ($formData->getParameters() as $par) {
        var_dump($par);
    }
}
```

The "Entry" type:
$this->tagType gets injeced in the constructor.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options){
    $builder->add('parameters', 'collection', array(
        'type' => $this->tagType,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
    ));
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Entity\Entry',
    ));
}
```

The "Tag" type:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options){
    $builder->add('field', 'text', array('label' => 'Key'));
    $builder->add('type', 'choice', array('label' => 'Type', 'required' => false, 'choices' => $this->getTypes()));
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Entity/Tag',
    ));
}
```

The javascript i use to add the fields:

```
var $childs = $container.find('.form-child');

fieldIndindex++; 

var template = $container
            .addClass('form-child')
    .attr('data-prototype')
    .replace(/\$\$name\$\$/g, fieldIndindex);

if($childs.length == 0){
    $container.prepend($template);
}else{
    $childs.last().after($template);
}
```

So, why isn't the entity typ detected?

Edit:

When i add the "data_class" option to my "collection" field, it works.

```
$builder->add('parameters', 'collection', array(
        'type' => $this->parameterType,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'options' => array(
            'data_class' => 'Entity/Tag',
        )
    ));
```

But setting it as default option in my "Tag" type should be enought. But why isn't it used?

Comment: Looks like your data_class might be wrong on your Tag

Comment: That's what i thought at first but I doublechecked it. I copied the namespace + classname to be sure.

Comment: Try making the data class the full path to the entity: 'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Tag' - I suspect what might be happening is that the data_class isn't used when you setup the form in the controller - only when you start embedding the forms then it needs a "hint" on how to make the object out of the data

Comment: I already use the full namespace. I shortened it for the example code here.

Comment: How do you add the tag forms with javascript?

Comment: I added the javascript i use to add the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.....

I was using the Symfony 2.1 syntax in 2.0. After changing setDefault options to getDefaultOptions, it now works.

Comment: Great. I suspected it was something simple!